# Running jenkins slave as service jenkins 2.89

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am trying to connect my windows slave as a service to jenkins 2.88.
I did so by starting the slave via webstart and then ran jenkins-slave.exe install to install the service.
When running a job for the second time, which checks out things from svn i get the following error:

```
Started by user XXX
Building remotely on Tobias_testnod (Excel) in workspace <PATH_TO_WORKSPACE>
Cleaning local Directory XXX/YYY
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\<path_>\.svn\pristine
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteFile(Util.java:290)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:370)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:389)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:369)
    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:389)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:225)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from <HOST>
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1655)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:308)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:904)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:986)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:902)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:838)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1202)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete <PATH>. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0,1 sec between attempts.
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:230)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:81)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1001)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:977)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:953)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2760)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:205)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:52)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:356)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: <PATH_TO_WORKSPACE> at hudson.remoting.Channel@1fe2698:JNLP4-connect connection from <HOST>
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:993)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:902)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:838)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1202)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Archiving artifacts
```

The service is running as my user in order for it to have all neccessary permissions.
Now my question in short is whether the approach of running the jenkins-slave jar from a service is properly supported from jenkins.
I could for example not install it from the window which appeared when starting via webstart as it did not have sufficent privileges. Instead I had to install it manually from the commandline running as admin.

So is the service option really working properly?
Or should i just drop it and connect from a commandshell instead?
If anyone knows exactly what is wrong of course I would be happy for any assistance regarding the error too :).
i am running java 1.8 on both the master and the slave.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a memory-related issue. See [this Jenkins bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50132) for a workaround.